# How to populate a new column in database using python script?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table in my database (**world_x**) called **'city'**:

```
| ID | Name           | CountryCode | District      | Info                    | Population |
+----+----------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+------------+
|  1 | Kabul          | AFG         | Kabol         | {"Population": 1780000} |       NULL |
|  2 | Qandahar       | AFG         | Qandahar      | {"Population": 237500}  |       NULL |
|  3 | Herat          | AFG         | Herat         | {"Population": 186800}  |       NULL |
|  4 | Mazar-e-Sharif | AFG         | Balkh         | {"Population": 127800}  |       NULL |
|  5 | Amsterdam      | NLD         | Noord-Holland | {"Population": 731200}  |       NULL |
```

I created the **Population** field using :

```
ALTER TABLE `world_x`.`city` 
ADD COLUMN `Population` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `Info`;
```

I used the following script to try and load the data but failed:

```py
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='****',password='********')

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("use world_x")
# This is for 10 rows but I will need all the rows for actual insert
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM city LIMIT 10")

new_column_data = []
for i in mycursor:
   s = json.loads(i[4])
   pop_before = s["Population"]
   pop_after_increase = int(round(pop_before * 1.1,0))
   new_column_data.append('Before: {}. After: {}'.format(pop_before, pop_after_increase))

output: of print(new_column_data):
['Before: 1780000. After: 1958000',
'Before: 237500. After: 261250',
'Before: 186800. After: 205480',
'Before: 127800. After: 140580',
'Before: 731200. After: 804320',
'Before: 593321. After: 652653',
'Before: 440900. After: 484990',
'Before: 234323. After: 257755',
'Before: 201843. After: 222027',
'Before: 193238. After: 212562']

sql = "INSERT INTO world_x.city Population VALUES (%s)"

mycursor.executemany(sql, new_column_data)
```

My goal is to fill the **Population** column with ["Before:, After:"] data <- This is one column.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should never copy data between columns. Each value should only be stored once!

Comment: Create a view instead. (And avoid data inconsistency.)

Comment: *but failed*...Please provide specifics to your issue. Errors or undesired results? Do you really want to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Comment: I think I should update as I managed to insert, and it populated rows starting at the bottom of Population column.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, you can do the whole process in the database with a single `update` query:

```
update city
set population = (info ->> '$.Population') * 1.1
```

Note that you should not be storing such derived information. You can use a computed column instead:

```
alter table city
    add column population double
    generated always as ((info ->> '$.Population') * 1.1) stored;
```

Comment: My assignment requires me to use a python script to do it.